# why twig langage 2 for vscode adds 4 tabs on the second line of twig file when formating it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am facing an issue using **codium** ( vscode ) when formating **twig** files :

I use the `twig language 2` extension in order to properly format my code, and it works, except on the second line which gets 4 tabs indentation ( same problem with another twig tag on first line, or just a comment line... )

The langage is set to `HTML(Twig)`, The formater is `Twig langage 2`  and this issue does not occur with other formaters

[image: twig code with an issue after extends tag]

Any help will be appreciated !